Issue with Transactions from Pure Proxy Owned by Another Pure Proxy in Polkadot.js
I have encountered an issue while using pure proxies on Polkadot.js. I created a pure proxy (proxy_1) owned by another pure proxy (proxy_0). When attempting to perform a tokens transfer from proxy_1, I receive the following error: balances.transferKeepAlive Cannot sign with a locked key pair.
Does this mean that a pure proxy cannot control other pure proxies? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.


Does this mean that a pure proxy cannot control other pure proxies?

There is no limit on how many nested proxies you can have.

Cannot sign with a locked key pair

This looks like a polkadot-js issue. Maybe try to use the extrinsics tab to construct the extrinsic manually. Ensure that you use the correct initial account for sending the transaction that polkadot-js tries to load the correct key pair.
